# How to draw single-line graph, using highcharts

Tags: html, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to create a single-line graph using highcharts.js, which has a treshold of 100 and is multi-color. For numbers above 100 the line is red, and for numbers less that 100 the line should get blue. I'd like to have something the same as picture. any thoughts? If there's a solution with another library, I appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Highcharts does not have a method to do this, as described, out of the box. Depending on the specific requirements, you could achieve the desired result, by processing the data beforehand to set the appropriate color, using a `'line` chart, with a separate series per segment, or an inverted `columnrange` chart, with a different point per segment, or perhaps I would try to use a `heatmap`, which would better handle the color determination, but would take a little more organization in handling the segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bar chart and colour it with a gradient, which is dynamically generated based on your data.

```
const data = [50, 95, 124, 78, 60, 108, 108, 120, 155, 87, 57, 76]
const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors
const options = {
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      pointWidth: 10
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: data.map((v, i) => {
        return [
            i/data.length, v > 100 ? colors[5] : colors[0]
        ]
      })
    },
    data: [100],
    type: 'bar'
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/cn3aj3jd/

Output: [image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot